# Serialized hashmap not updated

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

in my project I have many multi-thread processes communicating via sockets. I've an issue when I send a hashmap, update it, and then send it again. 
Map values I get after the second sending are not updated. 
I reproduced the problem in this sample class:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    //TEST

        static class MyKey implements Serializable{
            String nome;
            String nomeM;
            int altro;
            public MyKey(String nome, String nomeM, int altro) {
                super();
                this.nome = nome;
                this.nomeM = nomeM;
                this.altro = altro;
            }
            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((nomeM == null) ? 0 : nomeM.hashCode());
                return result;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                    return true;
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
                MyKey other = (MyKey) obj;
                if (nome == null) {
                    if (other.nome != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
                    return false;
                if (nomeM == null) {
                    if (other.nomeM != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!nomeM.equals(other.nomeM))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }

        }
        static class MyValue implements Serializable{
            int num;
            boolean bool;
            public MyValue(int num, boolean bool) {
                super();
                this.num = num;
                this.bool = bool;
            }
            public String toString() {
                return num + " " + bool;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            final int port = 9876;
            final MyKey myKey = new MyKey("foo","bar",42);
            Thread writer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ServerSocket ss = null;
                    try {
                        ss = new ServerSocket(port);

                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ss.accept().getOutputStream());

                        HashMap<MyKey,MyValue> map = new HashMap<>();

                        map.put(myKey, new MyValue(1,false));

                        System.out.println("writer step 1: "+map.get(myKey).toString());

                        oos.writeObject(map);
                        oos.flush();

                        map.put(myKey, new MyValue(0,true));


                        System.out.println("writer step 2: "+map.get(myKey).toString());


                        oos.writeObject(map);
                        oos.flush();

                        oos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread reader = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",port);
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                        HashMap<MyKey,MyValue> map = (HashMap<MyKey,MyValue>) ois.readObject();

                        System.out.println("reader step 1: "+map.get(myKey).toString());

                        map = (HashMap<MyKey,MyValue>) ois.readObject();

                        System.out.println("reader step 2: "+map.get(myKey).toString());

                        ois.close();
                        s.close();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            writer.start();
            reader.start();
        }
        //FINE TEST
}
```

This is what I get:

```
writer step 1: 1 false
writer step 2: 0 true
reader step 1: 1 false
reader step 2: 1 false
```

I also tried wrap the map in another class, but I had no success.

What am i missing?

Comment: What is your issue in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you did not call [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset--) on your `ObjectOutputStream` before writing the same object (here your map) in the stream so by default it considers that it has already been in the stream which is why you keep on seeing the previous state.

> Reset will disregard the state of any objects already written to the
>   stream. The state is reset to be the same as a new `ObjectOutputStream`.
>   The current point in the stream is marked as reset so the
>   corresponding `ObjectInputStream` will be reset at the same point.
>   Objects previously written to the stream will not be referred to as
>   already being in the stream. They will be written to the stream again.

**Try this:**

```
// Call reset before writing your map for the second time
oos.reset();
// Write the map
oos.writeObject(map);
```

**Output:**

```
writer step 1: 1 false
writer step 2: 0 true
reader step 1: 1 false
reader step 2: 0 true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the point is that, without calling reset, anytime I send an object wich is '==' a previous one, I will get the first state of the object. Is that right?

Comment: @Svech87 yes it is the idea